# Did not receive a transaction after a day from supportXMR

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mining-pools, transaction-confirmation, balance

I was using `supportXMR` for a few months and I had received 3 transactions of a little less than 0.3 XMR at certain times before. However, now on their end it shows that they sent their fourth 0.3 XMR yesterday with an assigned `Txn Hash` and 6 mixins,  yet on my `monero-cli` I don't see the transaction. I even upgraded from v0.11 to v0.12, yet the balance did not change.

My `monerod` is fully sync as it shows:

```
Refreshed 1557004/1557004, synced, daemon RPC v1.19
```

and using `show_transfers`, it only shows the ones up to this one and the date and the amounts match with the one mentioned on `suppoerXMR`, however, the last payment is not shown. Also `show_transfers pool` does not return anything. Is there anything wrong on my end? How can I verify this issue? Thanks.

Comment: That ^ guide provides a more elegant solution to this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and leave the answer here.

As of later March, there was a hard fork on the Monero network and the old databases (on Mac and Linux is found at `~/.bitmonero` folder should be removed and refreshed. So all needs to be done is the following:

```
1- Kill/close the running daemon
2- remove the `~/.bitmonero` folder. Note that it is a hidden folder.
3- Download the latest official Monero binary from [getmonero][1]. As of now it is `v.0.12` and paste it into a new folder.
4- Copy your keys and wallet files from the previous folder.
5- Run the monero daemon (`./monerod --detach`) and wait till it synced with the new fork. (You can use external untrusted nodes instead of running daemon locally, but that always comes with its own risk)
6- After daemon was synced connect the wallet to the daemon and you find the missing transaction.
```